How to amend an earlier git commit, the same way git --amend amends the latest commit?
EDIT: This question has been marked as a false duplicate. Answers based on git rebase --interactive are not usable in script and do not solve the given question.
My project contains various files that I use in turn. Currently, my script auto-commits every time a file is saved. In other words, a commit only contains changes to one file.

If the last commit, or HEAD, contains changes from the same file as the current saved file, auto- commit --amend occurs.
If HEAD contains changes from another file, the commit is done without --amend.


As I described, I use and save files alternately, and the last commit of the current file may no longer be HEAD, but HEAD~1 and commit --amend will no longer work in this case.

Right now I'm figuring out how to develop the script further and implement a solution similar to commit --amend so that:

the script also amends the previous commit.



The diagram shows an example of alternating use of two files.
Commits marked with a character contain changes in one file,
commits marked with numbers indicate changes in another file.
Each commit contains changes to only one file.
The first example shows when commit --amend is currently happening.
The second example shows the solution I'm currently looking to implement.

             master
             ↓
 1 --- 2 --- A 

$ git commit --amend → B
                   master
                   ↓
 1 --- 2 --- A     B
        \_________/

Problem:
             master
             ↓
 1 --- A --- 2 

$ ???
                   master
                   ↓
 1 --- A     2 --- B
  \_________/

Using git rebase --onto 1 A creates an unnecessary merge conflict. It is important to avoid merge conflicts because they are very difficult to manage if the non-interactive script is heavily used.
EDIT: (As acran explained well, this idea is no longer relevant)
Asking more simply, how to change 'Parent A' to 'Parent 1'?
$ git cat-file -p 2
tree 228f55
parent A


To be clear, does B already exist? Or is B an amended version of A that you want to create?

In the first example B amends A. Similarly, in the second example, A is no longer needed after B is committed. I would like to do this in my auto-commit script.

git rebase --interactive is one way to do this.
Note that part of what defines a commit is it's parent(s), so this is rewriting history.. We'll end up with something more like this
                   master
                   ↓
 1 --- A --- 2     2' --- B
  \_______________/


Just like --amend, this means if A or 2 is already shared with others, they will need to force pull.
Initial Setup
First, for those following along, we'll create a repo in the state you describe for demonstration.
git init
git commit -m initial --allow-empty

touch 1
git add .
git commit -m 1

touch a
git add .
git commit -m a

touch 2
git add .
git commit -m 2

touch b
git add .
git commit -m b

Rebase
Now, we use interactive rebase to rewrite history
git rebase --interactive c424a7d~ # sha of commit 1 (`~` means it's parent)

Your editor will open showing something like this, along with some help text below
pick c424a7d 1
pick aa32596 a
pick 61fd303 2
pick 6ff8a8f b

We want to edit it so that it looks like this
pick c424a7d 1 
drop aa32596 a
pick 61fd303 2
edit 6ff8a8f b

This means:

keep 1 the same
remove a so that 2 points to 1
keep 2 the same (other than the new parent)
keep b, but pause to verify and/or amend it first

Save and close. When prompted, validate that commit B matches what you are expecting, then run
git rebase --continue

Then we can validate that the new state matches what we're expecting:
$ git log --graph --reflog --oneline

* 438733e (HEAD -> main) b
* 5b86d44 2
| * 6ff8a8f b
| * 61fd303 2
| * aa32596 a
|/  
* c424a7d 1
* 9681553 initial


Good explanation! Suggest you add something about git commit --fixup and the --autosquash option to rebase.

I have never used either, but feel free to edit or add a new answer if they are useful here!

I'm not 100% sure what exactly you're trying to achieve. My best guess is that you want to go from here
                   master
                   ↓
 1 --- A --- 2 --- B

to either this
             master
             ↓
 1 --- 2 --- B'

or this
             master
             ↓
 1 --- B'--- 2

In either case git rebase is your friend as it allows your to edit the history and drop A and - as for the second case - to reorder commits.
But: in order for this to work it is important to understand how, especially that

In fact, B already contains all of A's changes

is only true because A is part of Bs history! I.e., B contains the changes by A only because A introduced them before.
So, simply dropping A completely would also drop any changes introduced by it and B' won't contain them anymore. Furthermore if A and B change the same file(s) this can lead to the merge conflicts you're experiencing!
So, in the above cases B' is not actually the same as B only with another history but instead B' = A+B!
And to combine two commits in that way you can use squash or fixup in interactive mode. For the first case you would run git rebase --interactive --root with:
pick c424a7d 1
pick 61fd303 2
pick aa32596 A
squash 6ff8a8f B

i.e., this will first move A to the end of the history and then squash it with B into a single commit.
For the second case just move the pick line for 2 to the end.

Bonus tip: if B did not happen yet and you want to "change" A you can use the edit command for that:
pick c424a7d 1
edit aa32596 A
pick 61fd303 2

This will rollback the worktree to A, you can make your changes, git commit --amend to A and then re-add 2 on top of it with git rebase --continue.
Alternatively you can commit B on top of your master with git commit --fixup A and the let git do the reordering and fixup automatically for you with git rebase -i --autosquash.
